using custom data for the list action in sonata admin
I am trying to have a listing where the data displayed are not managed by doctrine, but are being calculated depending on the filters.
More specifically, i have a list of entity (session), and i need to do some grouping on the prefix of each IP + display the count for each group, this can't be precalculated because it depends on some filters (date, ...)
My first idea was to have a temporary table and a hook like preList that i would use to fill empty/fill the table at before each query, and then let sonata read from that table.
Is it possible to :

have a custom controller called
read the filters from the parameters
do some custom logic and empty/refill a temporary table with calculated data
call the usual sonata routine to display that table

Another (more efficient) way would be if sonata allow to provide data outside of doctrine with some custom data provider but I can't find much in the documentation.
Thanks for any input on this.
